# python 3.7.4 : FLASK_SQLALCHEMY No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Debian "Linux mint 19.1" and python 3.7.4 and system have already 2.7 & 3.6 versions. I create an env but when I start to create database file with `db.create_all()` I have "...

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3' "

I have try by installing this packages [ quick-sqlite , pysqlite3 ]

> > > db.create_all()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 338, in dbapi
> > >           from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 1033, in create_all
>       self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 1025, in _execute_for_all_tables
>       op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 956, in get_engine
>       return connector.get_engine()
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 561, in get_engine
>       self._engine = rv = self._sa.create_engine(sa_url, options)
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py", line 966, in create_engine
>       return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts)
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/**init**.py", line 435, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
>       dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 343, in dbapi
>       raise e
>     File "/media/gabalawy/projetcs/training/Flask_Blog/env3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 341, in dbapi
>       from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite  # try 2.5+ stdlib name.
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/**init**.py", line 23, in 
>       from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
>       from _sqlite3 import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Answer (score 3):

I have Installed "pysqlite3"

> pip install pysqlite3

and modify

> "/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/pysqlite.py", line 341

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite  # try 2.5+ stdlib name.
```

to

```
from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite  # try 2.5+ stdlib name.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `_sqlite3` import is an internal import and should be available from your standard python installation. The fact that it's missing suggests a problem with your python build (did you compile it yourself).

I was able to fix this on suse by first ensuring that the `ncurses` were installed and then installing:

```
zypper install python-curses
```

On ubunti I guess the equivalent is (although I'm not sure its absence would give the same error):

```
sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev
```

(my complete build pre-requisites are:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

)